# Powershell smtp email with asterisk and number at the end

Tags: powershell

When I'm sending an email using powershell, at the very end of the email there is a 1 column, 2 row table with an asterisk in col0 row 0, and a number in col0 row1:

[image: a table with an asterisk in the top cell and the number 1509393 in the bottom cell]

I understand it's most likely a "time it took to run this script", but my end users don't want it on there. Is there a way to remove it?

What I'm doing is iterating through a list and getting all non-compliant items, then putting them into a table under their related area. So the body is basically a list of 7 tables, and sent like:

```
$smtpServer = "smtpserver.us"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From="productionmachine@email.com"

$msg.To.Add("user@email.com")
$msg.Subject = "Non Compliant Items"
$msg.Body = $body | ConvertTo-Html -Body $body -Head $style
$msg.IsBodyHtml = $true
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Comment: Yes, give me a minute to get the code put in there.

Comment: What is `$body`? Can you show us how it gets populated/assigned?

Comment: it's essentially a list of table tags, like 
<h2><b>Customer Support</b></h2>
<br />
<br />
<table>
<tr>
    <th><b>Work Instruction</b></th>
    <th><b>Owner(s)</b></th>
    <th><b>Performer(s)</b></th>
    <th><b>Modifed By</b></th>
</tr>

Comment: Man I really need to figure out how to format stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to overwrite `$body` with the actual results (or at least add them) earlier in the script.

When you then pipe `$body` to `ConvertTo-Html`, it get's bound to the `InputObject` parameter, is converted to a table with a single column, representing to sole property that a string has: it's length (in your case 150K characters).

But you don't notice, because `$body` has already been appended to the html body with `-Body $body`.

Remove `$body |` and it'll work. Or better yet, keep your `$body` and the actual results separated.

---

If you don't really need `ConvertTo-Html` for anything (it's primary capability is converting collections of live .NET object collections to html tables), just construct the body yourself.

Here-strings (multiline strings) and the string format operator (`-f`) are ideal for this purpose:

```
$htmlTemplate = @'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    {0}
  </head>
  <body>
    {1}
  </body>
</html>
'@

$msg.Body = $htmlTemplate -f $style,$body
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked to remove the * and the length, but now there is just an empty border sitting there

Comment: That's because you're not actually providing any input to `ConvertTo-Html`, so you end up with an empty table

Comment: Is there no way around removing this aside from not using ConvertTo-Html?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you're not really using it, why don't you just construct the entire html document yourself?

Comment: Is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve? I'm sorry, I'm very new to powershell so I'm just trying to go off of what I can see in the previous sharepoint/powershell scripts.

For reference, I'm iterating through a list and trying to put a link to the work instructions, as well as the people's name who own the process and the last modified  by. I just figured throwing it all in a string and making it an html type, it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, you've been a ton of help. I will try out your solution, as I am already building the body as you suggest. Thanks again for all your help!